# Restricting user access from Login page in Asp.net core mvc 2.1 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm currently doing an Asp.net core 2.1 MVC project. And in my login page of the project i want to check the users and give them access to different pages. That is, if the user is an Admin he should be redirected to the admin page and if it's a local user he should be redirected to the local user registration page. The code i used for checking is as follows.,
In my controller,

```
`var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(UserName);
        if (user != null)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user,Password, false, false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {   
               var log = await _context.LoginModels
                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.UserName ==UserName && m.Password == Password);

                if (log.UserType == "Admin")
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
                if (log.UserType == "User")
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

            }
        }
        TempData["LoginFeedBack"] = "JSalert();";

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "User name/password not found");
        return  RedirectToAction("Login","Account");
    }`
```

And i have 2 user types as admin and user. The current problem is that only the first user from the database(which is an admin) having the access or the loop is not checking other users. it is not giving any access to other users at all. 
How do i solve this problem ?

Comment: I don't see anything in your code out of the ordinary. I suggest setting a break point after you get the LoginModel and inspect the `UserType` variable.

Comment: Hi Jerry, thanks for your reply. i have already tried that. Added breakpoint after LoginModel and i can find that the user info , ie username and password, is passing (but only the first user from the database). no other users username and password is not passing it shows null value when inspecting.

Comment: Are your passwords stored as plain text in your `LoginModels`? If you are getting null back then `m.UserName == UserName && m.Password == Password` is obviously not matching any records. It is hard to tell where the problem is without seeing any of the other functions such as creating the LoginModels or the database.

Comment: No, both username and passwords are stored in local db using Entity Framework core and there are currently 6 values in the database comprising 3 user and 3 admin. The very first value is an admin value and it works perfectly. The Admin page get displayed and everything works fine. The problem is only when you try to login with other 5 users in the database. None of those login works it shows invalid username or password but its in the database as well.

Comment: Why don't you use roles? Assign a role to the user and work with them. Looks like you're reimplementing an already well established technology.

Comment: I'm sory what do you mean by Roles? if you mean user types Have already assigned types to the users as admin and user.

Comment: From your code and the other comments, I assumed you use .Net Core Identity as user management. This comes with extendable user accounts and roles.

Comment: yes i used .Net core identity to set authentication.

Comment: Update : i found that the local db that i used for checking users is not at all working (even not one user). There is a default table named AspNetUsers in the databases and the username and password are stored inside that table,which is set by default if you are using .net core Identity. But the problem is that you cant insert values to that table. Because the password field are hash protected and they used some cryptographic hash functions to protect the password that we insert. Now, i want to know how can i pass values to the table AspNetUsers.

Comment: `m.Password == Password` plaintext passwords are **highly insecure**. *Greatly* consider using the built-in methods of the `UserManager` class to do this stuff for you.

Comment: I used that still the problem persists

Comment: The problem has been solved. Thank you all for your efforts.